# When I send a post request in python...how do I

Tags: python, http, post, send

Have a "check"?

For example...
I would have a dictionary with the parameters to sent to the POST.

```
params = {'text':'how are you?', 'subject':'hi'}
```

then I would have

```
opener.open('theurl',urllib.urlencode(params))
```

The question is...those parameters work well with text-boxes, since I just put the value in there.  How about radio buttons? How do I signify which is "checked"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radio buttons has values too

```
<input type="radio" name="music" value="Rock" checked="checked"> Rock<br>
<input type="radio" name="music" value="Pop"> Pop<br>
<input type="radio" name="music" value="Metal"> Metal<br>
```

for that case {"music":"Rock"} in params

Comment: Note if a `value` attribute is omitted and that radio or checkbox is ticked, the submitted value will be `'on'`.